# Proof that $\frac{n^6+n^2}{n^7+3}$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergence-operator

I'm looking at a problem that follows:

Test if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^6+n^2}{n^7+3}$$ converges or diverges. I think I have a proof but it seems a bit awkward. You take out the 3 in the denominator and factor the numerator to get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^6+n^2}{n^7+3} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{n^7} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{n^5}$$ and replace 1 with $n^2$ and thus  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2+1}{n^5} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n^2}{n^5}$$ which holds for all $n > 1$ and then after cancelling, you can replace 2 with $n$ to get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^3}$$ which will hold for all $n > 2$ and since that is equal to $\frac{1}{n^2}$, it converges.

Is this proof valid? It seems I've either done too much work to prove this or I am missing some steps.

Comment: It seems too complicated. You can just write the expression as $1/n$ plus some other portion that you can argue is positive. Therefore the summation is lower bounded by a series you know is divergent.

Comment: You might want to fix this: $n^6+n^2=n^2(n^4+1)$.

Comment: Word "much" is too subjective. Is following much work?
$$\frac{n^6+n^2}{n^7+3} > \frac{n^6}{n^7+n^3} > \frac{n^6}{2n^7}=\frac{1}{2n}$$

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Ive done that and I got a completely different answer? Is this ok?

Comment: The typo still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Limit Comparison Test: compare the given series with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have shown that a series diverges that is larger than another series that is larger than your series. You could say an upper bound of your series diverges, but that doesn't mean your series diverges. For example:

$$ \sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \sum\frac{1}{n}$$
So does this that $\frac{1}{n^2}$ diverges? To show divergence, we want to create a lower bound for the series and show that it diverges.

$$\sum \frac{n^6+ n^2}{n^7 + 3} > \sum \frac{n^6}{n^7 + 3}$$
Is an example, and then you show that this lower bound diverges through other comparisons. You may do it however you choose. Let me know if you would like more help.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see, so if I want to prove something converges I make an upper bound, and if I want to prove something diverges I make a lower bound? Thanks for this. Also, do I need to study calculus for this (which is what I see on youtube) or should continuing analysis be ok (in your opinion).

Comment: Series and divergence tests are introduced in calculus, which is a prerequisite to analysis so I’m slightly confused here? How have you understood the concepts without any calculus knowledge?

Comment: There are lots of ways to prove divergence, you can make a lower bound, or you can do a limit comparison test (which is what people are recommending) which I can show you how to if you don’t know.

Comment: I was told that Real Analysis was just calculus but more rigorous, so I only know basic derivatives and integrals (no multivariable or tensor) but am currently reading Rudin (the easy version) and Intro to topological spaces by Lee.

Comment: Also, can I DM you about the limit test please. Edit: I just found out you cant DM anyone on here

Answer (score 1):

No - recall the (direct) comparison test: suppose $a_n, b_n$ are sequences of positive terms and $a_n \leq b_n$ eventually (that is, there exists $N$ such that $a_n \leq b_n$ for each $n \geq N$). Then if $\sum a_n$ is divergent, so too is $\sum b_n.$

Easier is to use, as @ShyamalSayak suggests, the Limit Comparison Test (I tell my students to do this too). If your argument were to hold, then I can say that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ is divergent by using the inequality $1 \leq n$ - but it's convergent by the p-series test and the Integral Test!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what the Integral Test is, or how to use it, but you're saying that its actually convergent? I fixed the question is that ok now?

Comment: No. Your sum is divergent by limit comparison. Also, please check your factoring - you made a grave error.